# MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException - Python Web Scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, accordion

The website I'm trying to scrape has the majority of its content displayed using accordions. I've identified the closed accordions by the class name "chevron-svg.left.chevron-down". I'd like to open them all, 81 in total.

I've tried using 'scrollIntoView' but I'm getting a 'MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException' error. What is the best way to do this? I've seen people recommend WebDriverWait but I'm not sure how to implement this.

My code is below, would really appreciate advice on what I'm doing wrong. The website and html are also below in a screenshot.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://sports.ladbrokes.com/event/basketball/american/nba/portland-trail-blazers-v-houston-rockets/230811255/all-markets"
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "chevron-svg.left.chevron-down")))
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("chevron-svg.left.chevron-down")

for element in elements:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

[image: Website]

[image: HTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing i found the issue being navbar: you scroll too low with "scroll to element", and click is intercepted with navbar. To fix this i just added `scrollBy` to your script.
Basically, change `execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)` with `execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(); window.scrollBy(0, -200);", element)`

Also, i don't know why you don't use `element.click()` instead of `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()`, works perfectly for me.

My test function was:

```py
def test(url = URL_test):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,
                              executable_path=Path('chromedriver.exe'))
    driver.maximize_window()
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5) # wait for load, too lazy to do proper way
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("chevron-svg.left.chevron-down")
        for element in elements:
            header = element.find_element_by_xpath('../div[contains(@class, "accordion-")]/span[1]').text
            print(header) # to test which ones fail
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(); window.scrollBy(0, -200);", element)
            element.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        driver.save_screenshot("screenshot1.png")
        pass
    return driver
```

Comment: I've tried using `element.click()` but it doesn't open the accordion for me.

Comment: So I've changed my search engine from Safari to Chrome and it now works! There must be some issue with using `click()` on Safari? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Potentially, i can't test Safari ATM, since i am Windows user :(